# Flutter device administrator permission

Tags: flutter, device, administrator

I'm trying to build an application that will lock the screen on a timer in Flutter. I'm wondering how to grant android device administrator permissions to an application in flutter. 
I've found this but it's not really helpful i feel for flutter.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#java

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed question explanation

Comment: hey, how did you achieve this functionality? can you share your solution with me?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no platform-agnostic Flutter implementation for locking a device screen programmatically. The Android specific [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) you were looking at is what you need to add admin permissions to the manifest file and implement your screen locking functionality.

You can add Android-specific Java or Kotlin code in a Flutter project as stated here: https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Makes sense, since I KNOW Apple wouldn't expose control like that as an API. @Diar, how is this going? I'm interested in Unlocking the device on call.